# Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String. error when filtering data grid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to filter my data grid here is my code

```
 dtSearch = dtRawMaterials.Select("RawMaterial_ID like '%" + txtSearchID.Text + "%'").CopyToDataTable
```

but when i enter a id in my text box and click search button the following error appears highlighting this line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you `DataTable` contain a column `RawMaterial_ID` if it does then:
For me next line of code works fine:

```
Dim dtSearch As DataTable
dtSearch = dtRawMaterials.Select(String.Format("RawMaterial_ID LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearchID.Text)).CopyToDataTable()
```

but you can try another approach - [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
Dim dtSearch As DataTable
dtSearch = dtRawMaterials.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of String)("RawMaterial_ID").Contains(txtSearchID.Text)).CopyToDataTable()
```

or multiline version

```
Dim dtSearch As DataTable
dtSearch = (From dr As DataRow in dtRawMaterials.AsEnumerable()
            Where dr.Field(of String)("RawMaterial_ID").Contains(txtSearchID.Text)).CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: What is error message? And did you tried `LINQ` methods?